# word-break only break after finished one?

Tags: html, css

HI I was just trying word break but there isn't a property for this only keep-all that will break the word on a - and break all, I want to let a break but only after the word finish but there isn't a property for this.

Comment: You want to break after a word has finished? That's default behaviour... Words that cannot be contained on a line automatically drop to the next line by default.

Comment: so i should use word-break normal and should work ?

Comment: Sure, or just omit the rule entirely.

Comment: just tried stillo like same, but on pc dont happend on responssive mode of apple only on iphone

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... and you have no code to support it. Please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: i cant make an example beacause as i said its only happening on my mobbile, and the sites or responsive test website arernt doing the same

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `word-break: keep-all` ?

You can see the different value for word-break [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Comment: tried, and nothing, maybe i should use !important but i cant see it on mobile and in pc dont happend

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p {white-space: normal; }
```

That should do it for you.